# Medicare Part A and a Health Savings Account (HSA)

Tags: united-states, taxes, hsa, hdhp, medicare

I'm over 65, have a part-time job with a high-deductable health plan and a Health Savings Account (HSA).

I want to take Social Security, which includes Medicare Part A automatically (retroactive for 6 months).

What is the tax penalty for contributing to an HSA while on Medicare Part A?

Answer (score 2):

[No](https://www.medicareinteractive.org/get-answers/coordinating-medicare-with-other-types-of-insurance/job-based-insurance-and-medicare/health-savings-accounts-hsas-and-medicare), you can't.

> If you enroll in Medicare Part A and/or B, you can no longer contribute pre-tax dollars to your HSA. This is because to contribute pre-tax dollars to an HSA you cannot have any health insurance other than an HDHP. The month your Medicare begins, your account overseer should change your contribution to your HSA to zero dollars per month. However, you may continue to withdraw money from your HSA after you enroll in Medicare to help pay for medical expenses, such as deductibles, premiums, copayments, and coinsurances. If you use the account for qualified medical expenses, its funds will continue to be tax-free.

Comment: That is the reason they tell you not to sign up for an HSA if you'll be eligible for medicare in the next 6 months....